# Add one single row to a specific sheet to an existing excel file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have one Excel file with multiple sheets. I want to read a specific sheet and add one single row to that specific sheet alone. In python pandas how to achieve this. If not possible in pandas, kindly suggest other libraries also. Thank you.

Comment: pandas has a `read_excel()` function that takes `sheet_name` as a parameter. Try using that. Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html